# How to calculate the time difference in seconds?

Tags: java, scala, datetime-format, zoneddatetime

I have two Datetime strings:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd-hh-mm-ss")
val startTime = formatter format ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
//...
val endTime = formatter format ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
```

How can I calculate the difference in seconds between `endTime` and `startTime`?

Comment: @RobertUdah: So, where do you see a duplicate? I am using ZonedDateTime

Comment: @OleV.V.In this case I'd appreciate if my question can be upvoted back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`:

```
// difference in seconds
ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(startTime, endTime)
```

But `startTime` and `endTime` must be `ZonedDateTime` objects, not Strings.

Just keep in mind that the result is floor-rounded - if the real difference is, let's say, 1999 milliseconds, the code above will return 1 (because 1999 milliseconds are not enough to make 2 seconds).

Another detail is that you can use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.of("UTC")`, as the result is the same.

Actually, if you're working with UTC, why not use `Instant.now()` instead? The `between` method above works the same way with `Instant`'s:

```
val start = Instant.now()
val end = Instant.now()

val diffInSecs = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start, end)
```

Comment: Do you mean this? `val start = Instant.now()`, `val end = Instant.now()`, `Instant.between(start,end)`

Comment: @Markus `ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start, end)`

Comment: How can I get Unix timestamp from `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))` or `Instant.now()` using `getEpochSecond()`?

Comment: @Markus `getEpochSecond()` return just the seconds value. To get the timestamp in milliseconds, use `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()` - or `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`

Comment: Could you please upvote my question?